# Big Nerd Ranch UIKit import

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why is that when I follow Big Nerd Ranch 4th edition I always need to import `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` for any class that contains `UIView, UIViewController, CG` stuff but the code in the solutions is somehow working without it? Is there any Xcode compliance set up that can be made to make it work well with just `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` import?
For example, in 12th chapter, where they create TouchTracker app, their code is working just fine with:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BNRLine : UIView

  @property (nonatomic) CGPoint begin;
  @property (nonatomic) CGPoint end;

@end
```

However, when I copy this code to my project it does not work without additional `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably use .pch imports. Basically it means that before every source file it will be imported and executed. [This tutorial](https://techfuzionwithsam.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/how-to-add-pch-or-prefix-pch-file-in-xcode-6/) seems like a one you could see whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

They may have additional imports inside a precompiled header file with a .pch extension. You can search for this file in their project.

In Xcode, if you command-click on the import statement you can bring up the detailed list of imports and that should answer any question you may have about what is being imported.